# Error in rfInit from the RFsimulate() function in R

Tags: r

I am using the functions `RMderiv` and `RFsimulate` from the packages `RandomFields` and `geostatsp`, respectively. However, the function `RFsimulate` gives the error message:

```
Error in rfInit(model = list("Simulate", setseed = eval(parse(text =
"quote(set.seed(seed=seed))")),  :  searching a simulation method for
'RMderiv': searching a simulation method for 'RMderiv' Running out of
list of methods. Are the RFoptions() too restrictive? You get (more)
internal information if you set R
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(RandomFields)
library(geostatsp)

res_r <- 10 ## cell resolution
scale <- 1000 
r <- GridTopology(c(0,0), c(res_r, res_r), c(301, 501))
model <- RMderiv(RMgauss(), scale=scale)
map_r <- geostatsp::RFsimulate(model=model, x=r)
```

The code works when the cell resolution is 20. Thanks in advance for any advice allowing me to resolve this issue.